# Usages of "Observe"

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*observe*".  There are two [definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/observe) of the verb "*observe*" at issue:

> 1.1  Watch (someone or something) carefully and attentively
>   2.2 Perform or take part in (a rite or ceremony)

If I write this:

> They ***observed*** the ground-breaking ceremony.

Is the sentence ambiguous because both def 1.1 and 2.2 would work?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not ambiguous to a native speaker, because from context it was a single ceremony, which could be watched, so "they " are presumed to be watchers. This is mainly because the other sense is rare.

To be taken  the other way, that is, that "they" participated, native speakers might phrase, something like this:

- They observed the *tradition* of the ground-breaking ceremony.

In this phrasing, "observed" is almost like "followed".

But more likely, we would use  "participated in ", or maybe  "performed."